# Service which creates multiple children with dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

If I want to have a service which creates multiple objects which have injectable dependencies how do I code that?

```cs
public class MyCreator : ICreator
{
  private readonly IAdapter _adapter;
  public MyCreator()
  {
    _adapter = adapter;
  }
  public List<MappedObjects> Map()
  { 
    List<MappedObjects> mo = new List<MappedObjects>();
    foreach (ObjectToMap otm in ObjectToMap)
    {
      mo.Add(new MappedObject(otm, InjectedDependency dep));
    }
  }
}
```

If I register `MyCreator` with DI, will it know how to provide `InjectedDependency`?

**EDIT:** `InjectedDependency` is not one instance which should be passed to each `MappedObject`. I want a new instance of `InjectedDependency` for each new `MappedObject`.

Perhaps that means I have to create some kind of Factory object which know's how to create instances of `InjectedDependency`. I cannot provide more code because I don't know how to articulate what I need in C#.

I'm using teh inbuilt DI with .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: What are you using for Dependency Injection? What version of .NET is this?  Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with, if possible, your expected outcome

Comment: You may also want to ask yourself, why it is needed. Mapped objects are normally data vessels, while injected dependencies tends to be logic. Why do you want to mix them in one object?

Comment: In my case `MappedObject` is a vessel, whilst `InjectedDependency` is logic which I want to compose with each instance of the vessel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed need a factory:

```
public class MyCreator : ICreator
{
  private readonly IInjectedDependencyFactory _factory;

  public MyCreator(IInjectedDependencyFactory factory)
  {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public List<MappedObjects> Map()
  { 
     return ObjectToMap.Select(otm => new MappedObject(otm, _factory.Create())).ToList();
  }
}
```

Obviously, you will have to write the factory class and interface and register them with your DI container.

---

You could also inject the DI container itself, `IServiceProvider` to get your new services directly from the container, given that that already *is* a factory. However, many people might consider this a code smell and the Service Locator pattern (that's what it would be) is not held in high regard nowadays. Other people might consider it wasteful to implement a factory on top of a factory. I guess there is no right way, you will have to live with some people calling it wrong, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code testable, you need to inject the implementation of InjectedDependency in your MyCreator constructor.